# Inheriting specflow editor options

Tags: specflow, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to inherit the editor properties from a single specflow.json configuration file for multiple projects?

After VS2022 release Specflow extension lost its General Options ([Tools > Options > SpecFlow > General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evyhf.png)) which had contained Editor format configuration.

[Specflow docs say](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/visualstudio/settings-options.html) you can configure it with specflow.json file but it is not so convenient when you have a bunch of projects.
i would like to have something like the following for many projects:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://specflow.org/specflow-config.json",
  "ide": {
    "editor": {
      "gherkinFormat": {
        "indentDataTable": false,
        "indentExamples": true,
        "indentExamplesTable": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We keep all our steps separate from test projects and we [include them with specflow.json at the project level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA9Im.png) using stepAssemblies like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://specflow.org/specflow-config.json",
  "stepAssemblies": [
    { "assembly": "Test.Contract" },
    { "assembly": "AnotherTest.Contract" },
  ]
}
```

Its scheme contains a property called "configFilePath" but it does not seem to be working for me. It just does nothing, like there is no property specified at all.

I've been expecting something like i could extract all the editor options into a single specflow file located at a solution level then i just get all the properties for every project specific files from it.

The following example would work perfectly:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://specflow.org/specflow-config.json",
  "stepAssemblies": [
    { "assembly": "Test.Contract" },
    { "assembly": "AnotherTest.Contract" },
  ],
  "ide": {
    "specFlow": {
       "configFilePath": "C:\\src\\specflow.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Where configFilePath is the single editor configuration file.

Did i miss something? is there a way not to duplicate it?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a [repro]? Can you give us more information about your project structure? We would also need to see all applicable specflow.json files.

Comment: yeah, sure, sorry, is this going to work out?

Comment: What do you mean by "but it does not seem to be working to me" -- are you getting an error? What is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: it just does nothing like there is no property specified at all

Comment: I added your last comment to the question text itself. I think this is a good question, and one many people will likely have since the UI is being removed from Visual Studio.